# TSQL similar query different results

Tags: sql

This query:

```
SELECT ROWNUMBER,FATHERITEMNO,FATHERVARIANT
FROM STOCKBILLMAT WHERE FATHERVARIANT ='LOCK' 
AND FATHERITEMNO ='U5138'
```

gives me 2 results:

```
12779526   "U5138"   "LOCK"
12779527   "U5138"   "LOCK"
```

But the following query on the same table:

```
SELECT ROWNUMBER,FATHERITEMNO,FATHERVARIANT
FROM STOCKBILLMAT WHERE FATHERVARIANT ='LOCK' 
AND ROWNUMBER > 12818500 
AND ROWNUMBER < 12818590
```

gives me these 5:

```
12818532   "U5318"   "LOCK"
12818533   "U5318"   "LOCK"
12818558   "U5318"   "LOCK"
12818559   "U5318"   "LOCK"
12818560   "U5318"   "LOCK"
```

My problem is that unless i'm having a seriously blonde moment, all the rows returned by the second query "should" have been returned by the first query too!

Notes:

1. I only added the ROWNUMBER range to narrow down the results because I knew roughly where they were. If I omit that filter and just scroll down, I see the 5 results, but not the 2 from the first query...
2. STOCKBILLMAT is a table, not a view.
3. The queries are executed on the same database, in the same session of QueryExpress, same everything.
4. There are multiple databases on the server with roughly the same data, and the same thing happens on the others too.

Any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your first query from `U5138` TO `U5318`:

```
SELECT ROWNUMBER,FATHERITEMNO,FATHERVARIANT
FROM STOCKBILLMAT WHERE FATHERVARIANT ='LOCK' 
AND FATHERITEMNO ='U5318'
```

Comment: I had to re-read that about 6-7 times before I saw the difference. I was looking everywhere but the obvious haha! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The queries are off by the row numbers.  The first query returns the ROWNUMBERs 12**7**79526 and 12**7**79527, but the second one is a different range that begins with 12**8**.